# Finding repeating substrings in a string

Tags: xml, oracle, search, plsql, duplicates

I am new to PL/SQL and I have been given this task.  I have XML messages that are being stored in a Receive_XML table with the field name of XML_DATA.  There has been issues where the sending location is sending split sequences which is causing them problems when they receive it back.  A split sequence is where we receive a sequence #1, then sequence #2, and then sequence #1 again.

What would be the best way to search through the Receive_XML table to find instances where any sequence is repeated more than once without knowing the sequence number.  Here is an example of an XML record we receive.

```html
<MESSAGE>
 <HEADER>
  <MESSAGE_TYPE>ProductionSequence</MESSAGE_TYPE>
  <TIMESTAMP>2019-10-29 10:00:01</TIMESTAMP>
 </HEADER>
 <PRODUCTION_SEQUENCE>
  <SEQUENCES>
   <SEQUENCE SEQUENCE_ID="8764          " SEQUENCE_ID_PARENT="">
    <PIECE_GROUPS>
     <PIECE_GROUP>
      <PIECE>
       <PIECE_ID>514236947</PIECE_ID>
      </PIECE>
      <PIECE>
       <PIECE_ID>578645897</PIECE_ID>
      </PIECE>
     </PIECE_GROUP>
    </PIECE_GROUPS>
   </SEQUENCE>
   <SEQUENCE SEQUENCE_ID="6452          " SEQUENCE_ID_PARENT="8764">
    <PIECE_GROUPS>
     <PIECE_GROUP>
      <PIECE>
       <PIECE_ID>514236947</PIECE_ID>
      </PIECE>
      <PIECE>
       <PIECE_ID>578645897</PIECE_ID>
      </PIECE>
     </PIECE_GROUP>
    </PIECE_GROUPS>
   </SEQUENCE>
   <SEQUENCE SEQUENCE_ID="8764          " SEQUENCE_ID_PARENT="6452">
    <PIECE_GROUPS>
     <PIECE_GROUP>
      <PIECE>
       <PIECE_ID>514236947</PIECE_ID>
      </PIECE>
      <PIECE>
       <PIECE_ID>578645897</PIECE_ID>
      </PIECE>
     </PIECE_GROUP>
    </PIECE_GROUPS>
   </SEQUENCE>
  </SEQUENCES>
 </PRODUCTION_SEQUENCE>
</MESSAGE>
```

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Bill

---

What I finally found worked for me was:

```sql
select SEQUENCE_ID, count(SEQUENCE_ID) Counter
from (
  select SEQUENCE_ID
  from   Receive_XML tbl,
       xmltable('/MESSAGE/PRODUCTION_SEQUENCE/SEQUENCES/SEQUENCE' 
                PASSING xmltype(tbl.xml_data)
                COLUMNS SEQUENCE_ID VARCHAR2(30) PATH '@SEQUENCE_ID')
  where tbl.id = 4451
) rs
group by SEQUENCE_ID;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following *PL/SQL*. It counts @SEQUENCE_ID attribute. So greater than 1 value means it is a duplicate.

> PL/SQL

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (ID INT, xml_data XMLType);
INSERT INTO tbl (ID, xml_data)
VALUES
(1, '<MESSAGE>
    <HEADER>
        <MESSAGE_TYPE>ProductionSequence</MESSAGE_TYPE>
        <TIMESTAMP>2019-10-29 10:00:01</TIMESTAMP>
    </HEADER>
    <PRODUCTION_SEQUENCE>
        <SEQUENCES>
            <SEQUENCE SEQUENCE_ID="8764          " SEQUENCE_ID_PARENT="">
                <PIECE_GROUPS>
                    <PIECE_GROUP>
                        <PIECE>
                            <PIECE_ID>514236947</PIECE_ID>
                        </PIECE>
                        <PIECE>
                            <PIECE_ID>578645897</PIECE_ID>
                        </PIECE>
                    </PIECE_GROUP>
                </PIECE_GROUPS>
            </SEQUENCE>
            <SEQUENCE SEQUENCE_ID="6452          " SEQUENCE_ID_PARENT="8764">
                <PIECE_GROUPS>
                    <PIECE_GROUP>
                        <PIECE>
                            <PIECE_ID>514236947</PIECE_ID>
                        </PIECE>
                        <PIECE>
                            <PIECE_ID>578645897</PIECE_ID>
                        </PIECE>
                    </PIECE_GROUP>
                </PIECE_GROUPS>
            </SEQUENCE>
            <SEQUENCE SEQUENCE_ID="8764          " SEQUENCE_ID_PARENT="6452">
                <PIECE_GROUPS>
                    <PIECE_GROUP>
                        <PIECE>
                            <PIECE_ID>514236947</PIECE_ID>
                        </PIECE>
                        <PIECE>
                            <PIECE_ID>578645897</PIECE_ID>
                        </PIECE>
                    </PIECE_GROUP>
                </PIECE_GROUPS>
            </SEQUENCE>
        </SEQUENCES>
    </PRODUCTION_SEQUENCE>
</MESSAGE>');

select ID, SEQUENCE_ID, count(SEQUENCE_ID) Counter
from (
  select ID, SEQUENCE_ID
  from   tbl,
       xmltable('/MESSAGE/PRODUCTION_SEQUENCE/SEQUENCES/SEQUENCE' 
                PASSING tbl.xml_data 
                COLUMNS SEQUENCE_ID VARCHAR2(30) PATH '@SEQUENCE_ID')
) rs
group by ID, SEQUENCE_ID;
```

> Output

```
+----+-------------+---------+
| ID | SEQUENCE_ID | Counter |
+----+-------------+---------+
|  1 |        6452 |       1 |
|  1 |        8764 |       2 |
+----+-------------+---------+
```

Comment: I'll check this out.  Thanks!

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

This example xpath seems to work:

```
with Receive_XML as (
select xmltype('
<MESSAGE>
     <HEADER>
<MESSAGE_TYPE>ProductionSequence</MESSAGE_TYPE>
         <TIMESTAMP>2019-10-29 10:00:01</TIMESTAMP>
     </HEADER>
     <PRODUCTION_SEQUENCE>
         <SEQUENCES>
             <SEQUENCE SEQUENCE_ID="8764          " SEQUENCE_ID_PARENT="">
                 <PIECE_GROUPS>
                     <PIECE_GROUP>
                         <PIECE>
<PIECE_ID>514236947</PIECE_ID>
                         </PIECE>
                         <PIECE>
<PIECE_ID>578645897</PIECE_ID>
                         </PIECE>
                     </PIECE_GROUP>
                 </PIECE_GROUPS>
             </SEQUENCE>
             <SEQUENCE SEQUENCE_ID="6452          " 
SEQUENCE_ID_PARENT="8764">
                 <PIECE_GROUPS>
                     <PIECE_GROUP>
                         <PIECE>
<PIECE_ID>514236947</PIECE_ID>
                         </PIECE>
                         <PIECE>
<PIECE_ID>578645897</PIECE_ID>
                         </PIECE>
                     </PIECE_GROUP>
                 </PIECE_GROUPS>
             </SEQUENCE>
             <SEQUENCE SEQUENCE_ID="8764          " 
SEQUENCE_ID_PARENT="6452">
                 <PIECE_GROUPS>
                     <PIECE_GROUP>
                         <PIECE>
<PIECE_ID>514236947</PIECE_ID>
                         </PIECE>
                         <PIECE>
<PIECE_ID>578645897</PIECE_ID>
                         </PIECE>
                     </PIECE_GROUP>
                 </PIECE_GROUPS>
             </SEQUENCE>
         <SEQUENCE SEQUENCE_ID="6452          " SEQUENCE_ID_PARENT="8764">
                 <PIECE_GROUPS>
                     <PIECE_GROUP>
                         <PIECE>
<PIECE_ID>514236947</PIECE_ID>
                         </PIECE>
                         <PIECE>
<PIECE_ID>578645897</PIECE_ID>
                         </PIECE>
                     </PIECE_GROUP>
                 </PIECE_GROUPS>
             </SEQUENCE>
         </SEQUENCES>
     </PRODUCTION_SEQUENCE>
</MESSAGE>
')  XML_DATA from dual )
select
xt.dup
FROM   Receive_XML xt,
       XMLTABLE('//SEQUENCE'
         PASSING xt.xml_data
         COLUMNS 
          dup VARCHAR2(20)  PATH '@SEQUENCE_ID[.= ../preceding-sibling::SEQUENCE/@SEQUENCE_ID]'
        ) xt
where dup is not null
```

Comment: This will get me on the path of what I need. I didn't know reading XML was so easy.  I was trying to treat it as a string (thus the title).

Thank you very much for your help!